# Getting MySQL Error #1064 when trying to insert data

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on [this website](http://www.intechgrity.com/create-login-admin-logout-page-in-php-w/#), but when I try to insert the below statement I get the following error:

> ```
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
> to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
> '`INSERT INTO  login_admin (user_name, user_pass)
> VALUES
> (
> â€˜adminâ€™, SHA(â€˜a`' at line 7
> ```

```
INSERT INTO login_admin (user_name, user_pass)
VALUES
(
‘swashata’, SHA(‘swashata’)
)
 
INSERT INTO login_admin (user_name, user_pass)
VALUES
(
‘admin’, SHA(‘admin’)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to run two queries at once, not one. Each `INSERT` statement is a separate query. You have to separate queries with a delimiter (`;`).

In fact, unless you have some bad settings on your server ([allowing multiple queries at once](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)), you can't even do that and need to run them as two separate queries, or combine them using multiple VALUES lists.

Also, please note that you cannot use tick marks (`‘`) to indicate a string value. You need to use single quotes (`'`) instead.

The best approach is to rewrite your queries as:

```
INSERT INTO login_admin (`user_name`, `user_pass`) VALUES
( 'swashata', SHA('swashata') ),
( 'admin', SHA('admin') )
```

Finally, I *really* hope you aren't using `SHA` to generate passwords. That's not secure. Use [PHP's built-in password functionality](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

Comment: Also see the manual page for [mysqli multi query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) when the need does arise.

Comment: ok sir, thank you much, i tried it and works, thank you friend